# Fresh linux installed boot

Tags: boot

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 via USB on a 500GB HDD and I also have an old HDD of 40GB.
I erased everything and now I only have Ubuntu installed, but on the Loading Operating System windows it give me an error saying `grub rescue`.
I searched for solutions but I am kind of a noob and I didn't solve this.
Now I am on the USB trying linux because I can not enter the installed one.

Comment: So you deleted windows but the entry is still there in grub, and you cannot boot the new linux (which is in grub too). Is that correct? Did you remove physically your old drive?

Answer (score 0):

Boot from your USB drive and reinstall grub onto your boot device with

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```